# Android Update a List with a Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, list

im creating a program that need to update a list every x seconds, so i created a ListActivity and a Thread. The ListActivity call the thread, and it sends the information, but the list doesnt update until ALL the thread is finished.

EXAMPLE: if i put a for in the thread for 5 times, you cant see the list until that 5 times are ended.

CODE HERE:

ListActivity:

```
public class ValuesActivity extends ListActivity {
ArrayList<Values> valueList;
ListView list;
ValuesAdapter adapter;
Request request;
String name;
NewValuesListener newValues;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.values);        

    list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Bundle bundle=this.getIntent().getExtras();
    name =bundle.getString("name");


    newValues=new NewValuesListener(){
        @Override
        public void onNewValues(ArrayList<Values> val) {

            valueList = val;
            adapter=new ValuesAdapter(ValuesActivity.this,valueList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    };

}

 public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    valueList=new ArrayList<Values>();
    request=new Request("XXXXXXXX",name,newValues);
    adapter=new ValuesAdapter(this,valueList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);       
    request.run();

 }

}
```

Thread:

```
public class Request extends Thread  {
private String values;
private String server;
private NewValuesListener vActivity;


public Request(String values,String server,NewValuesListener activity){
    this.values=values;
    this.server=server;
    this.vActivity=activity;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    ConnectToServer con=new ConnectToServer(server);

    int cd=5;
    while (cd>0){

        String response=con.read(values);
        String[] channelValues=new String[2];
        ArrayList<Values> arrValues=new ArrayList<Values>();
        channelValues=LoadData.stringToArray(response);
        for (int i=1;i<3;i++){
            Values val=new Values("000"+i,channelValues[i]);
            arrValues.add(val);

        }

        vActivity.onNewValues(arrValues);
        try {
            yield();
            sleep(10000);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        cd--;
    }       
}
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ValuesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<Values> values;
private LayoutInflater lInflater;

public ValuesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Values> val) {
    this.lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.values = val;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {return values.size();}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {return values.get(arg0);}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {return arg0;}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ValuesView list = null;

    if (arg1 == null){
        arg1 = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.values_adapter, null);

        list = new ValuesView();
        list.channelName = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.lblValueName);
        list.value = (EditText) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txtValue);

        arg1.setTag(list);
    } else
        list = (ValuesView) arg1.getTag();

    Values val = (Values) getItem(arg0);
    list.channelName.setText(val.getName());
    list.value.setText(val.getValue());
    return arg1;
}

class ValuesView
{
    TextView channelName;
    EditText value;
}
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: you do not need to create an Adapter Everytime. Could you post your ValuesAdapter?

Comment: i created the adapter because i need a list view with a TextView and an EditText. So i think i need it.

Comment: yes But you can create it once. Can you post your adapter?

Comment: Let me understand. You want to show a item for every iteration of the while cycle?

Comment: you'll probably want to move your updates on the ui thread.

Comment: no, the server returns a list of elemts name and value. i had to create a list with those elements and update it every iteration of the thread. Im going to post the adapter 1 sec

Comment: basicly i want to remove the elements of the list, and create a new one with the values that the thread change(ArrayList)

Comment: Definitely part of your problem is that you keep recreating the adapter. You should create the adapter only once, in `onCreate()`. Create a method like `setValues(ArrayList<Values> values)` in the adapter and when you want to update the data in the adapter, just call that method (make sure that you call that method from the UI thread).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not update your list from thread other than GUI, and from your example I suppose this is what you are doing. The best way is to use AsyncTask and either use handler to communicate update information to GUI thread or handle updates in onPostExecute where you can schedule next AsyncTask as a next for-iteration.

Comment: i have a problem with that. The update have to be in other thread because i had to update all the list every 1 second for example. and the information that i have to obtain is sent by a server.

Comment: And i dont update the list out of the GUI Thread, i update an Array, the one who use the adapter to put the elements on the list. On the GUI Thread, i only put a new adapter to my list.

Comment: But from what I see setAdapter( is called from background thread, actually android should throw exception if some operation on UI is performed from non-GUI thread. What android device are You using?

Comment: no, setAdapter is on the ValuesActivity (The main Thread). The Thread that had to run in background is the other one. That thread returns an Array of values. And the main thread set the new adapter with those values.

Comment: vActivity.onNewValues(arrValues); is called inside run() - which is executed on background thread. This makes code inside onNewValues( to be executed on background thread. You can check it insde debugger.

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you do this nside the thread after the data has changed:

```
Activity_Name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

Comment: happend exactly the same, black screen until all the thread end